# Problema al correr una aplicación y me aparece debug

Tags: ios, swift

Hola amigos tengo una duda ya que apenas estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Xcode, estoy haciendo un ejemplo de aplicación móvil en iOS el problema que tengo está en que cuando doy clic al botón el cual me direccionará a otra vista, justo no veo el cambio ya que se activa el debug y no se como desactivarlo o como hacer que siga corriendo mi aplicación espero y alguien me ayude se los agradecería mucho les dejo una imagen de como se queda.

[image: Así se me queda y no puedo avanzar mas]

Comment: Lo que aparece no es el debug, es un error en tu `app`, podrias indicar el código que estas utilizando??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es una excepción y la aplicación se cerrará si la corres sin Xcode.

Lo que podrías hacer es seleccionar la opción de breakpoints, darle en + y seleccionar "Add Exception Breakpoint.." y das enter.

Con esto se detendrá exactamente donde esta ocurriendo la excepción y te dará más detalles del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigo, me ha sido de ayuda.